# I don't understand how to calculate the sum of the sums of every possible sub-array using nested loops

Tags: c++

The question the homework asks is:

Write a function, secondSmallestSum that when passed an int array of any length greater than 1 will calculate the sum of the elements of every possible sub-array and then return the second smallest sum found. It is possible for the smallest and second smallest sums to have the same value.

Sub-arrays are contiguous ranges of elements within an array. For example, if you have an array of length 4, {1,2,3,4}, then the complete set of sub-arrays is:

{1}, {1,2}, {1,2,3}, {1,2,3,4}, {2}, {2,3}, {2,3,4}, {3}, {3,4}, {4}

the sum of each sub-array is then:

1, 3, 6, 10, 2, 5, 9, 3, 7, 4

The main function for this problem must call your readNumbers function, then pass the new array to your secondSmallestSum function, display the second smallest sum found and finally delete the array.

My code so far prints numbers that the user inputs.

```
#include <iostream>

int *readNumbers(int n)
{
    int *a = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        std::cin >> a[i];
    }
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    int length = 5;
    int *ptr = readNumbers(length);
    printNumbers(ptr, length);
    return 0;
}
```

I expect this array (AN EXAMPLE) {4,0,9} to output the sub-arrays of {4}, {4,0}, {4,0,9}, {0}, {0,9} and {9}. The sums for each array would output as: 4,4,13,0,9 and 9. The total sum is 39.

Comment: I would recommend going for vectors rather than Carrays. Anyway it's your choice.
Try implementing another dimension.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far and try to identify a specific question that you need answered.

Comment: @SouyamaDebnath Since this is homework, sadly there is probably no choice in using raw arrays.

Comment: Try posting your erroneous code here. We can not make the algorithm for you :)

Comment: The code that fails is very useful in a question. For one thing you might be almost there and only need a small correction. If the error is large, we have a better feel for what you know and how best to approach explaining what went wrong and how, along with strategies to avoid the problem again in the future in addition to merely how to make it better. The old [give a man a fish](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day;_teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime) thing in action.

Comment: Hello everyone, thank very much for your answers. But I am a complete novice at C++ and was wondering how someone more adept at the language would tackle the problem.

Comment: Just a bit of advice to get you started, Try to make the array {1,2,3,4} -> {10,9,7,4} _(You will achieve better performance)_ and then run the double loop on each element.

Comment: An experienced C++ programmer would use a [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Side note: do not forget to release the memory that you have allocated. That which you `new[]`, you should `delete[]`. It doesn't matter much with a small program like this, but it matters quite a bit when you are writing longer-lived and memory-hungry complicated programs. Correctly managing resources is a good habit to get into early. `vector` helps you by managing the memory it uses for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a first look, it definitely occurs that let's run a double loop till the end of the array for each element and find the sums of element along with it.

That gives you the complexity of O(n2) *roughly speaking*
Now, do you want to add `3+4` for the 2nd iteration (when you're looping for 2) while you have already calculated for 1st iteration? I wouldn't...

So instead I would save those incremental additions like this:

```
    for (int *i = ptr + l - 2; i >= ptr; i--) {
        *i = *i + *(i+1);
    }
```

This would give me `{1,2,3,4} -> {10,9,7,4}`

Now run the double loop:

```
    for (int *i = ptr; i < ptr + l; i++) {
        cout << *i << " ";
        for (int *j = i+1; j < ptr + l; j++) {
            cout << *i - *j << " ";
        }
    }
```

Now you have all the sums. and you can do all the required operations. For your example the second smallest: You can add the following code in that double loop

```
        if (secondsmallest >= x) {
            if (smallest >= x) {
                secondsmallest = smallest;
                smallest = x;
            }else{
                secondsmallest = x;
            }
        }
```

Find the correct place to add it and replace `x` with suitable notation :)

Cheers...
If you find this answer helpful - consider upvoting :)